# Cloud Functions for Firebase: accessing BigQuery not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I need to connect to BigQuery from Firebase cloud functions and store some data.
The BigQuery located in another Google project, so I suppose to use a .json file with primary key.
Unfortunately, my solution is not working.

I have following code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const bigquery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const path = require("path");

exports.testBigQuery = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  var bigqueryClient = bigquery({
      projectId: '(project name)',
      keyFilename: path.join(__dirname,'bigQuery.json')
  });

  const dataset = bigqueryClient.dataset("mat");
  const table = dataset.table("meraki_data");

  function insertHandler(err, apiResponse) {
      if (err) {
          response.send({err : err, response : apiResponse});
      } else {
        response.send({err : "No error", response : apiResponse});
      }
  }

  table.insert({
      ap_mac: "TESTsfsadfads",
      rssi: 1,
      is_associated: false,
      client_mac: "TEST"
    }, insertHandler);

});
```

And after function call (I use Postman) I have following response:

```
{
  "err": {
    "code": "MODULE_NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

Running this script on my local machine using node.js works well.

Where I was wrong?

Comment: Please update with versions of `nodejs` engines, `firebase-admin`, `firebase-functions`. I suggest you use `nodejs v10`. Check if you have the latest versions in `package.json`, then delete `node_modules`, run `npm install`. Check all steps from [Upgrade to v1.0+ from beta](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff). After update and install (including `firebase-tools`), then **do a full re-deploy** `firebase deploy`. Last but not least, check if all `require` files have correct names/paths and exist (`bigQuery.json`); also check the name of the entry file must be `index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 90% sure that means there's a dependent package missing.Check you package.json to make sure you have all dependencies there.  Delete your node_modules folder locally and `npm install --production` to reinstall everything the same way google is trying to install it.  Then run it locally again.